# SQL Query if statement use days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure for SQL Server I can create if statement use 1 day like Sunday but if I want to use 2 days like Sunday and Monday I don't know how to use it.

My stored procedure in SQL Server is like this:

```
if @DateName = 'Sunday'
begin
    Set @Status = 2
    return
end
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

To check for two different days in your IF statement, try the following. This checks for both Sunday and Monday.

```
Declare @DateName Varchar(25) ='Sunday'
Declare @Status int =0

IF(@dateName = 'Monday' OR @dateName = 'Sunday') 
begin
    Set @Status = 2
end
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @DateName Varchar(25) ='Monday'
Declare @Status int =1

if @DateName in ('Sunday','Monday')
begin
    Set @Status = 2
end

select @Status
```

Returns
2

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
begin
if @DateName='Sunday'
    Set @Status = 2
 else if @DateName='Monday'

    Set @Status = 1
end
```